# Event listener 'componentchanged' is only firing for 'rotation' and not 'position'

Tags: aframe

When trying to detect the movement of the camera's position using the `componentchanged` event listener, I'm only able to detect the rotation when outputting `evt.detail.name` to the console.

To move the camera around in the scene with the keyboard, I'm using the [A-Frame Extras library](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras).

Here's the code I'm using that outputs the rotation only...

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
        document.querySelector("a-entity[camera]").addEventListener("componentchanged", function (evt)
        {
                // The console message outputs 'rotation' and never outputs 'position'
                console.log("Event name: " + evt.detail.name); 
            if(evt.detail.name === "position")
            {
                console.log("Camera has moved from " + evt.oldData + " to " + evt.newData); 
            }
            else
            {
                 console.log("position has not changed"); 
            }
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls position="0 0 0">
      <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled:false"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a tick function to check for changes in position on the **camera rig**:

```
tick: function () {
  var rigEl = this.el;
  var currentPosition = rigEl.object3D.position;
  // Compare to this.lastPosition (a vector3 you create)
  this.lastPosition.copy(rigEl.object3D.position); 
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to use a tick function only because for our purposes, I didn't want to have continuous polling.  My solution was posted in a previous comment.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The position is almost always going to move, a tick function is negligible. You can throttle it if you want (AFRAME.utils.throttleTick). I don't recommend using DOM events for something that updates so frequently. Your solution is off because the position will change as the key is held down....not just on keydown. For future readers stumbling upon this thread, go with this solution.

Comment: When I use the `tick` option, I see the X, Y and Z position remain the same when outputting to the console if I don't move the camera.  For my purposes, I want the position updated when the key is held down **and** also on `keydown`.  I unchecked my answer as the go-to answer since my scenario is going to be different than others stumbling upon this thread.

Comment: I disagree, it's not situational. The tick function is best practice over a hard DOM keydown event to detect position changes. It's how game engines work. Other things can modify position rather than just keydown, it's very specific to WASD-controls.

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree-the tick answer isn't a great solution. Instead of calling function code once an event happens(in this case a change to the camera position) you're calling the tick function continuously(I'm guessing through setInterval) leading to a lot of unnecessary processing. It's not just the tick function call on the setInterval-but also any of the code the end developer places in that function(yes, you can shield this out by storing the position of the camera in the tick function and constantly comparing it to the new position so code only executes on position change-but why would you bother with all of this, when firing an event on an actual position change saves you the hassle?)

Keydown has its own drawbacks(the obvious one being AFrame on mobile doesn't use keydown-you'd have to lock onto touchstart or something), but it's still better than the alternative.

Comment: It's not through setInterval, it's a requestAnimationFrame that batches together all the other tick calls. The keydown is bad practice. What happens if you add other controls that changes the position? What happens if another component changes the rig's position? A keydown listener that you have no control over how often it gets called, up to the DOM, is not great. The user is nearly always moving, especially in VR, it's gonna get called anyway. If nothing changes, then the processing is negligble.

Comment: Good to hear its requestAnimationFrame. Better than I thought. As far as what happens when another component changes the position-yep; you're 100% correct-definitely an issue with this approach. But that's even more of a reason I think this should be handled at the library(AFrame) level. I don't think notification of camera position changes are such an unusual use case that they should be pushed to user code(but YMMV). Oddly, events are setup for rotation change events, so why would you be all for that, but not position updates? Ideally, you would have both(or simply a camera move event)

Comment: In VR, the camera position is changing *constantly*, it's redundant. As I said, game engines would poll. Not even to mention, you sometimes don't even want to detect local position, but global position with world matrices...the same goes for rotation. Mouse event is extremely flaky, poor practice, and non-general solution.

Comment: I'm not talking about mouse events-I'm talking about having AFrame fire events on camera position change(it doesn't seem to do this, it only does this for camera rotation changes). This would be irrespective of controller. While I won't disagree with you on game engines, please understand that's not the only use for AFrame.

Comment: It doesn't do it because the movement-controls component is attached to and changing the rig's position, not the camera. Why would the camera fire an event when its local transform nor its component data has changed. That's why you use a tick, because you may need to factor in multiple levels of transforms and guaranteed it's checked on each frame, regardless of the scene structure and parent components. And because events have overhead / unpredictable. This is regardless of the "use" of A-Frame. Also, A-Frame is inherently a game (or real-time) engine, that's a fact (we co-created A-Frame).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue.  You can do the following...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
    var cameraEl = document.querySelector("#camera");
    var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();

    function getCameraPosition() 
    {
        worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(cameraEl.object3D.matrixWorld);
        console.log("Position: " + worldPos.x + " " + worldPos.y + " " + worldPos.z);
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) 
    {
        // check if keys pressed are W, A, S, D and Up, Down, Left, Right
        if (evt.keyCode == 87 || evt.keyCode == 65 || evt.keyCode == 83 || evt.keyCode == 63 || evt.keyCode == 38 || evt.keyCode == 37 || evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 40)
        {
            getCameraPosition();
        }
    });     
});
```

You'll want to also add an ID to your camera...

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls position="0 0 0">
  <a-entity id="camera" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled:false"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```